# Derivative of step function is Dirac delta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The derivative of a locally integrable function $f$ is by definition the linear functional

$$\phi \mapsto -\int_\mathbb{R} \phi'(x)f(x) dx$$

Using this definition, why is it that the derivative of the step function is the dirac delta function?

Since the derivative is a *linear functional*, I don't understand why we should get a *function* like the dirac delta. Linear functionals and functions are not the same...

Comment: Hint: $\int \phi^{'}(x) f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty \phi^{'}(x)dx = \dots$.  Remember $\phi$ is drawn from $C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I'm confused even with the definition. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian But following your hint, I get $\phi(0)$. How does that imply the derivative is the Dirac delta?

Comment: Just a quick comment.  The Dirac delta is emphatically not a function.  If any function is zero everywhere except a point, then its integral is zero, so there is no hope of finding a function which behaves like a delta.  It only makes sense as a distribution or a measure, both of which are defined as linear functionals on an appropriate space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity let's assume the step function $f$ is $f = \chi_{[0,\infty)}$. Let $\phi$ be a test function, then

$$(Df)(\phi) = -\int \phi'(x) f(x) dx = -\int_0^\infty \phi'(x) dx  = - \phi(C) + \phi(0) = \phi(0)$$

where $C$ is any large number such that $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x\geq C$. Thus $Df$ is the delta function at $0$.